# Superset Localization BI

Tags: presto, trino

Is there any way to localize all elements in the Superset BI System into Russian?
It was possible to translate the buttons and some of the elements, but can't find the way to translate the months on the X axis within the graph.

Comment: The months on a graph are, presumably, based on your data and are not UI elements. If your data is not in Russian then it won’t display in Russian

Comment: It turns out that I need to make changes in the request itself and the values within the axis will change themselves?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? This is not covered by ANSI/ISO SQL.

Comment: @jarlh trino/presto